# JQuery apply bind to all children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#eventsContent").children().each(function(){
            $(this).bind("mouseenter", function(){
                $(this).css("background","#F5F5F5");
        });
    });
});
```

I have tried this a couple different ways, but this is the jist of what i've done.

I have a container div with numerous divs within it. I want to bind a MouseEnter event to each inner div respectively (and eventually a mouseout, once i see what's done it will be easy to expand upon).

Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#eventsContent div").bind("mouseenter", function(){
  $(this).css("background","#F5F5F5");
});
```

Comment: This wont work for ALL the divs separately will it?

say you mouse over div1, i'd like only div 1 to change.

Comment: Yes, it will work for all of the DIVs independently. When the mouse enters one of the DIVs, the background of that DIV only will change.

Comment: It works because "this" refers to the element on which the event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try a hover:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#eventsContent").children().each(function () {
        $(this).hover(
             function () { $(this).css("background", "#F5F5F5") },
             function () { $(this).css("background", "#000000") }
        );
    });
});
```

(Didn't test code)

Comment: Same concept as what i have written, i believe my problem lies in the selector.